# Source code for Nhibernate 3.1.0.4000 is missing in GitHub, where could I find it?

Tags: nhibernate

We are using this specific version of Nhibernate in our application. And now we come across a situation where we want to debug an issue through Nhibernate, But I am unable to find source code for this specific version in Nhibernate git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source package can be downloaded here

https://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.1.0.GA/

Other versions *(latest at the moment is **5**)*:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried 3.1.0.GA from their GIT. It seems to have breaking changes from the version 3.1.0.4 which I am looking for.  I also have tried 3.2.0.GA. Both 3.1.0.GA and 3.2.0.GA giving run time error, thats why I am trying to find this specific version 3.1.0.4 source code.

Comment: The version of a package I gave you link to - is: `[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("3.1.0.4000")]`. That is what you asked for